# Obtaining rotation and translation matrix from homogeneous transformation matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, robotics, eigen3

I have following piece of code:

```
Eigen::Matrix4f transformation = myMethod(); // homogenous transformation matrix
std::cout << "transformation = " << std::endl << transformation <<  std::endl << std::endl;
Eigen::Isometry3f estimate = Eigen::Isometry3f(transformation);
r = estimate.rotation(); // rotation matrix
t = estimate.translation(); // translation matrix
std::cout<<"r = " << std::endl << r << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout<<"t = " << std::endl << t << std::endl << std::endl;
```

It prints:

```
transformation = 
     1.0000002384185791  4.9265406687482027e-07 -4.5500800638365035e-07  -2.384185791015625e-07
-5.2062489430682035e-07      1.0000003576278687  5.4357258250092855e-07 -3.5762786865234375e-07
 4.9866633844430908e-07 -4.6970637868071208e-07      1.0000002384185791  -2.384185791015625e-07
                      0                       0                       0                       1

r = 
     1.0000001192092896  7.2572328235764871e-07 -3.9811814644963306e-07
-6.7004600623477018e-07     0.99999994039535522  4.5586514829665248e-07
  5.422648428066168e-07 -4.4537293319990567e-07     0.99999994039535522

t = 
 -2.384185791015625e-07
-3.5762786865234375e-07
 -2.384185791015625e-07
```

Here, I am trying to obtain rotation and translation matrices from homogeneous transformation matrix. I guess translation matrix is the first three elements of the last column of homogeneous matrix and rotation matrix is top left 3x3 matrix. Translation matrix is returned correctly above. But rotation matrix is not exactly the top left 3x3 matrix of the homogeneous matrix.

I guess I am missing some basic concept here. What am doing wrong?

Comment: where did you define `r` and `t`? `transformation` does not contain methods `rotation` and `translation`, did you mean to write `estimate.rotation`/`estimate.translation`?

Comment: For `Eigen::Transformation` (as @0xbachmann noted, `Eigen::Matrix` does not have these methods), `.rotation()` will extract just the rotational part of the `.linear()` part (i.e., remove the scaling and shearing). If you want to have the top-left 3x3 matrix, just use `.linear()`.

Comment: What you are missing is some linear algebra, homogenous 4D coordinates are not directly transformable into a 3D coordinate transformation matrix.

Comment: The 4D homogenous part allows for translations to be added, you will miss them in the 3D only part (https://www.brainvoyager.com/bv/doc/UsersGuide/CoordsAndTransforms/SpatialTransformationMatrices.html)

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake while renaming my context specific variables. `translation()` and `rotation()` are methods of variable `Eigen::Isometry3f estimate`. Now corrected that.

Comment: Can you try if you get back the same altered numbers with `Affine3f` or `AffineCompact3f`? In theory, `Isometry` is expected to trigger a [shortcut](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/a6dc930d16be86cffba1f2926dea196abab0fe71/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h#L1015).

Comment: @tevemadar It depends on what version OP uses. In Eigen 3.3 this optimization was not there yet: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3.3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h?ref_type=heads#L1049

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of [`Transform`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Transform.html) describes the different storage modes:

- **Affine**: the transformation is stored as a (Dim+1)^2 matrix, where the last row is assumed to be [0 ... 0 1].
- **AffineCompact**: the transformation is stored as a (Dim)x(Dim+1) matrix.
- **Projective**: the transformation is stored as a (Dim+1)^2 matrix without any assumption.
- **Isometry**: same as **Affine** with the additional assumption that the linear part represents a rotation. This assumption is exploited to speed up some functions such as `inverse()` and `rotation()`.

And this actually [happens](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/a6dc930d16be86cffba1f2926dea196abab0fe71/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h#L1015), `Isometry` simply returns what was stored in the constructor:

```
template <typename Scalar, int Dim, int Mode, int Options>
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC typename Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, Options>::RotationReturnType
Transform<Scalar, Dim, Mode, Options>::rotation() const {
  return internal::transform_rotation_impl<Mode>::run(*this);
}

template <int Mode>
struct transform_rotation_impl {
  template <typename TransformType>
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC static inline const typename TransformType::LinearMatrixType run(const TransformType& t) {
    typedef typename TransformType::LinearMatrixType LinearMatrixType;
    LinearMatrixType result;
    t.computeRotationScaling(&result, (LinearMatrixType*)0);
    return result;
  }
};
template <>
struct transform_rotation_impl<Isometry> {
  template <typename TransformType>
  EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC static inline typename TransformType::ConstLinearPart run(const TransformType& t) {
    return t.linear();                     <===================== here
  }
};
```

But, this is version **v3.4**. As @chtz points out in the comment, this description and the optimization itself are not present in **v3.3**, [`rotation`](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/3.3/Eigen/src/Geometry/Transform.h?ref_type=heads#L1049) uses no "switchboard", but directly calls a fixed function:

```
template<typename Scalar, int Dim, int Mode, int Options>
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC const typename Transform<Scalar,Dim,Mode,Options>::LinearMatrixType
Transform<Scalar,Dim,Mode,Options>::rotation() const
{
  LinearMatrixType result;
  computeRotationScaling(&result, (LinearMatrixType*)0);
  return result;
}
```

`computeRotationScaling` (the method directly below the linked one) then calculates SVD, and that's where numerical inaccuracies can get introduced:

```
template<typename Scalar, int Dim, int Mode, int Options>
template<typename RotationMatrixType, typename ScalingMatrixType>
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC void Transform<Scalar,Dim,Mode,Options>::computeRotationScaling(RotationMatrixType *rotation, ScalingMatrixType *scaling) const
{
  JacobiSVD<LinearMatrixType> svd(linear(), ComputeFullU | ComputeFullV);

  Scalar x = (svd.matrixU() * svd.matrixV().adjoint()).determinant(); // so x has absolute value 1
  VectorType sv(svd.singularValues());
  sv.coeffRef(0) *= x;
  if(scaling) scaling->lazyAssign(svd.matrixV() * sv.asDiagonal() * svd.matrixV().adjoint());
  if(rotation)
  {
    LinearMatrixType m(svd.matrixU());
    m.col(0) /= x;
    rotation->lazyAssign(m * svd.matrixV().adjoint());
  }
}
```

`Isometry` in v3.3 is practically an `Affine` with some parts switched off (like `scale` stops you with an assert, and there are some more).

> I guess I am missing some basic concept here. What am doing wrong?

Seemingly you're using an older version of the library. Consider trying the code with v3.4.